When I navigate to the URL and get the contents of the TABLE tag, it's empty
I am trying to scrape data from this website https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures/AALM11/agenda?page=1&size=100& and when I look at the DevTools > Elements, it has a TABLE tag with the data inside TR and TD tags (dates, values, etc.), but when I try to parse the HTML with Selenium or bs4 the data disappear and instead I see a <div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true">. What can I do to extract the information I need?
My code
deb = 'AALM11'
link_agenda = 'https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures/' + deb + '/agenda?page=1&size=100'
driver.get(link_agenda)

html_source = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table').get_attribute('outerHTML')

The result
<table id="" class="anbima-ui-table anbima-ui-table-responsive  anbima-ui-table-mobile">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span style="width: 80px;"><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;"><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;"><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 45px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;"><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 90px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;"><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 55px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 80px;"><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 45px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 75px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></td>
            <td><span><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 75px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></td>
            <td><span><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 125px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></td>
            <td><span><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 75px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></td>
            <td><span><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></td>
            <td><span><div class="skeleton-container" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100px; height: 18px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></span></td>
        </tr>
...

I was expecting to see this instead
<table id="" class="anbima-ui-table anbima-ui-table-responsive  agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-1 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-2 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-3 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-4 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-5 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-6 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-7 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-8 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-9 agenda-ativo-page__table--liquidado-10 ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span style="width: 80px;">Data do evento</span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;">Data de liquidação</span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;">Evento</span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;">Percentual / Taxa</span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 110px;">Valor pago</span></th>
            <th><span style="width: 80px;">Status</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="agenda-data-evento-0" class="normal-text">13/01/2022</span></td>
            <td><span id="agenda-data-liquidacao-0" class="normal-text">13/01/2022</span></td>
            <td><span id="agenda-evento-0" class="normal-text">Pagamento de juros</span></td>
            <td><span id="agenda-taxa-0" class="normal-text">4,3500 %</span></td>
            <td><span id="agenda-valor-0" class="normal-text">R$ 53,434259</span></td>
            <td><span id="agenda-status-0" class="anbima-ui-flag anbima-ui-flag--small anbima-ui-flag--small--green " style="max-width: 96px;"><label class="flag__children">Liquidado</label></span></td>
        </tr>
...


You're issuing a simple GET, but a web request is also made up of cookies and request headers. These might be important to getting the response you want; web sites often quietly reject simple requests because they usually mean its a bot and not a user. Examine the successful request in your browser and try to emulate it as closely as possible.

@Schwern That's not the issue. See my answer.

There's also the issue of Javascript. If you examine the source of the GET request you'll see it contains Javascript. You'll need to ensure this Javascript runs the same as in your browser.

The problem is that the table data is dynamically loaded. When the browser is loading the page, it signals to Selenium that the page is done loading but the content of the page is still loading in the background. So your code is executed and it scrapes the partially loaded page. To fix this, we need to wait for something that indicates that the page is done loading. I chose to wait for the absence of all the <div class="skeleton-container" ...> elements. Once those are gone, the table data load is complete and the table data is available.
Working code...
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

deb = 'AALM11'
link_agenda = 'https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures/' + deb + '/agenda?page=1&size=100'
driver.get(link_agenda)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.skeleton-container")))
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table")
print(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))


When I tried to run this script, it returned this error:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"table"}

That's odd... I ran this several times when writing this code and it never failed to find the table. Are you sure you used just my code? You included the wait in the line above? You could add a wait that finds the table as well but it shouldn't be necessary.

Well, i'm running this script in google colab, it could be that?

No idea. I've never run anything in google colab... dunno what that is.

i tried to run in vscode and got it right. thank you very much

If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.
